# Storybook-angular error - Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-providers, angular-environmentproviders

after upgrading storybook from 6.5 to version 7.0.23 with angular 16 I met this error:

`Type 'EnvironmentProviders' is not assignable to type 'Provider'`

Currently found that docs are changed, and providers should be in `applicationConfig`

```
const meta: Meta = {
  title: 'Example',
  component: ExampleComponent,
  decorators: [
    // Define application-wide providers with the applicationConfig decorator
    applicationConfig({
      providers: [
        importProvidersFrom(BrowserAnimationsModule),
        // Extract all providers (and nested ones) from a ModuleWithProviders
        importProvidersFrom(SomeOtherModule.forRoot()),
      ],
    }
  ],
};
```

But it does not make effect to fix this error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The config works, but also **we need to delete** the `component` **property** from the Storybook object. It is deprecated, but not so obvious that it will broke the build, also it is not highlighted as deprecated unfortunately.
more info https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#angular-removed-deprecated-component-and-propsmeta-field